# String translate from Array , str_replace?

Tags: php, arrays, translation

String translate from Array , str_replace?

I have an array

```
 $money = array(
    "USD"=>100,
    "BAT"=>1000,
    "RIEL"=>2000
    );
```

And I define as constant to be translate:

```
define("const_infor","Your __TYPE__ are:  __AMOUNT__  __CURRENCY__ .<br><br>");
```

Bad WAYS:

```
  echo "Your balance are :";//more constant here
  foreach ($money as $currency=>$amount){
      echo $money.$currency."; ";
  }
```

I try to output(GOOD WAYS):

```
  $tmp1 = "";
  $tmp2 = "";
  foreach ($money as $currency=>$amount){
    $tmp1 .= $money;
    $tmp2 .= $currency;
  }
echo str_replace(ARRAY("__TYPE__","__AMOUNT__","__CURRENCY__"),ARRAY("Balance",$tmp1,$tmp2),const_infor);
```

BUT What I want is the output should be :

```
Your Balance are: 100 USD; 1000 BAT; 2000 RIEL
```

How can I pass the `$currency`. to `str_replace` ?

Anyone can help me to do this.?

Comment: what's the point in all these constants?

Comment: you have to explain using words of English language, whats so bad in "bad ways" and why "good ways" are good.

Comment: But what you want could be this instead:

Comment: I found the solutions.thanks both guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try that:

```
foreach ($money as $key => $cur)
  echo $cur.' '. $key;
```

Comment: @lEnAk could you please explain what's so bad in this way?

Comment: @lEnAk WHAT do you want to translate? Numbers?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly you wanna do but if it's only output
try

```
printf("Your Money %f %f %f", $money["USD"], $money["BAT"], $money["RIEL"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, below is just kind of a parser for doing what you want.. Try and see if it fits your needs:

```
function replace($string, $name = '', $value = '')
{
   if ( !empty($name) )
   {
      str_replace('{'.$name.'}', $value, $string);
   }
}


$string = 'Your balance is {bal1} USD, {bal2} BAT';

$string = replace('bal1', $money['USD'], $string);
$string = replace('bal2', $money['BAT'], $string);
$string = replace('bal3', $money['GBP'], $string);

print $string;
```

Comment: It depends on how big an array you have produced :-) I disagree in your argumentation - I think it is a lot better than using a lot of constants - and in this way you can use arrays instead of making longer and longer strings with an array. :)